# How to set colour of text from a certain point forward

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, colors, jtextpane

I'm building a small conversation agent, where the text looks like follows:

[image]

I would like to set the System's text to always be red. The text is all placed in a JTextPane.

How can I accomplish this?  I have tried doing the following:

`agentTextPane.setForeground(Color.red);` after the system's text is added, and then switching back to black, however that changes all the text in the `JTextPane`.

This is how the system's text is added:

```
//'output' is a stringBuilder
output.append("\nSystem: ").append(tempOutput).append("\n");
agentTextPane.setText(output.toString());
```

Comment: Could you show us some of your code?

Comment: @blackpanther - I added some code, but there isn't really much more I can add.

Comment: @trashgod, undeleted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15669307/230513), you can define an attribute set representing a desired style. For example,

```
StyledDocument doc = (StyledDocument) jtp.getDocument();
SimpleAttributeSet system = new SimpleAttributeSet();
StyleConstants.setFontFamily(system, "Serif");
StyleConstants.setForeground(system, Color.red);
doc.insertString(doc.getLength(), "...", system);
```

The styles can be progressive, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15600689/230513).

[image]

See [*Text Component Features*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html) for more examples.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to use HTML tags to format your Strings in terms of colour. The following reference may be useful. [setting JTextPane to content type HTML and using string builders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9071389/setting-jtextpane-to-content-type-html-and-using-string-builders)

```
 output.append("<font color=\"red\">");
 output.append("\nSystem: ").append(tempOutput).append("\n");
 output.append("</font>");
```